# With CalDAV account on lumia 920 WP8 GDR2, new events disappear

Tags: sync, nokia-lumia-920, calendars

I tried to set my account (of course calDAV with emails and calendar) on my lumia 920 with GDR 2.
I can get my emails but what happens when I create an event on the calendar is surprising me: when I create an event, it disappears after about 5 seconds. BUT, when I refresh my calendar on my computer, the event appears. Incredible, isn't it ?
Well, my question is : do you have an idea of any setting I should change so that the events I create stay on my phone ? 
I hope you can help me, sorry if my english is not that good...
Regards,
Fabien (from France, sorry :-)

Comment: Is this with a Gmail, Outlook or other account?

Comment: This is à calDAV but neither gmail nore Outlook (I tried to configure it with the trick I found on this website but it seems not to work... It's actually an account for my job (french national education, I'm a high-school director)

Comment: What email system does your company run, is it Exchange based?

Comment: No, this isn't an exchange based account. The company uses Convergence (by Oracle), Do you know this product ?

Comment: @NeilTurner The adress of the server for our agenda + email looks like this : [link] https://login_email@agenda.ac-orleans-tours.fr/caldav/dav/principals/firstname.name@ac-orleans-tours.fr/ . I don't know if it helps...

Comment: The issue may be with the server, so you'll have to check with the server admins. Also, the SSL cert. used maybe invalid which can also cause problems for the phone.

Comment: @NeilTurner : I try to re-post my comment, I add some spaces in the adress of the server, so that you can read it entirely: The adress of the server for our agenda + email looks like this : h t t p s ://login_email@agenda.ac-orleans-tours. fr/caldav/dav/principals/firstname.name@ac-orleans-tours. fr/ .  I don't know if it helps...

Comment: @NeilTurner : the SSL settings must be correct becausE it works for the emails. Am I right or are the settings of SSL really different for email and agenda ?

Comment: If you visit the link you posted in a browser, it will give warnings about the SSL cert.

Comment: @NeilTurner : Indeed, but it's normal : I replaced the values of my accounts with other values, so that I don't let the real ones on the web (I could be hacked, right ?). I'm sure the adress of the calDAV server is ok because it's the one that is given in the how-to for android and iOS phones.